# Ratios of co-occurrence probabilities can encode meaning components

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'studying NLP these days through CS224N, which is NLP lecture in Stanford, and I had a question of co-occurrence probability.

I can understand that each first row and second row shows co-occurrence probability, but it's hard to understand last row. Hard to figure out what it is...

In lecture, said that meaning component is something like female to male, king to queen. I thought would be gender in this example.

In last row I thought it was condition, but hard to find correlation between Large and Small..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awfyN.png)